# Install Linux Mint on hp 14r022la

Tags: linux-mint, system-installation

I want to install Linux Mint 17.3 on this computer (which already has Linux 12.04 from HP):

I used an USB like usual, but is now working. I tested the USB in another computer and is working fine.

This is my BIOS configuration:

[image: Bios Configuration]

This in my boot with the USB connected:

[image: Bios with usb]

As you can see, I have two options with the USB. I tried both but is not working. The only thing I get is the screen of loading Linux Mint logo.
I don't want a double boot. I want to replace the entire system

Comment: Do you want to dual-boot it with Ubuntu or replace it with Linux Mint?

Comment: UEFI boot or Legacy?

Answer (score 0):

@GAD3R as you can see in my first image, the legacy is "on" and secure is "disable".

In the images you can't see, but I changed the " usb" as first.

Still not working. I can go further of Linux Mint Logo.

I want to replace the entire system, not double boot

Thanks.